# What command to select data like left join

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to get data from my database without using a 'left join' Because it causes low performance (displaying 6000 records takes 1.16 min). What command do I need to do like left join.

My DB Structure

```
Table 1
Doccode (String) |   Inv_no (String) |   Inv_date (Date) |
AA0012                2122240           13.07.2014
AA0013                2122360           13.07.2014
AA0014                2122480           14.07.2014
AA0015                2122510           14.07.2014
AA0016                2122612           15.07.2014

Table 2
Inv_no (String) |   close_date(date) |  close_time(time) |
AA0013                22.08.2014          11:11:12
AA0015                21.08.2014          11:14:12
AA0016                04.08.2014          12:11:12

Table 3
Inv_no (String) |   return_date(data)  | return_by
AA0012                09.08.2014         Admin
AA0013                06.08.2014         Admin
```

I want to get result like this below

```
Doccode    |      Inv_no   |    Inv_date    |   close_date  |    close_time |  Return_Date
AA0012           2122240        13.07.2014      <null>         <null>          09.08.2014
AA0013           2122360        13.07.2014      22.08.2014     11:11:12        06.08.2014
AA0014           2122480        14.07.2014      <null>         <null>           <null>
AA0015           2122510        14.07.2014      22.08.2014     11:11:12         <null>
AA0016           2122612        15.07.2014      22.08.2014     11:11:12         <null>
```

In this case will use left join (I knew it) but it is very..very slow, and actual data is 6000 record only!

What other way is there to get result like a left join? please help

Note: I use firebird 2.5.

Comment: Please learn to format your code after 8 posts here

Comment: Use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to format table output

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is not a slow command by itself, it depends on how well your tables relations are designed. "slow" in mysql most commonly means, it has to look at a huge amount of rows to get the defined resultset. To debug this, use `EXPLAIN SELECT ......`. There is a column *rows to investigate* or similiar wording, when the number is higher than ~10, that key is very slow. Use index on all columns it is using as a key column.

Comment: Also, create a SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ project

Comment: index's key is inv_no in each table.. it still very slow and command
'EXPLAIN' can't use with firebird 2.5

Comment: @user3793478 In ISQL you can get the plan by using `SET PLAN` before executing the query, most other query tools for Firebird also have an option to obtain the query plan (for example FlameRobin displays it by default on the _Statistics_ tab). I'd also suggest you include the query itself.

Comment: @Adrian sqlfiddle doesn't have Firebird support

Comment: Besides the plan and the query, also include the DDL of the tables themselves and any (extra) indexes on them.

Answer (score 0):

What you should use to get a result like that is exactly a left join.

There may be other ways to get the same result, but a left join is absolutely the fastest possible way. Any other way would be a lot more complicated. If you for example would use subqueries to get the related data, the database would at best optimise it to the same thing as doing left joins.

With only 6000 records a query like that would run for a few milliseconds. It sounds like you are missing indexes on the tables that you join. You should at least have indexes on `Table2.Inv_no` and `Table3.Inv_no`.

Comment: i already have index in Table2.Inv_no and Table3_Inv_no  .. and so what the next!

Comment: @user3793478: Can you show the query that you are using? Can you view the query plan for the query so that you can see if it actually uses the indexes?